# Emacs evil-escape does not work

Tags: spacemacs, osx, terminal-emacs

I have just installed spacemacs recently.
I press `fd` to switch from `insert state` to `normal state`, but it does not work.

The combination keys `fd` shown on the editor then disappear, but when I press `SPC` key, it inserts a space character in the buffer.

This is spacemacs behavior when I pressed `fd`
[image: spacemacs behavior when I pressed <code>fd</code>]

Is there any configuration that I missed?

Comment: I see you tagged the question with `terminal-emacs`.  Does it work in the GUI application?

Comment: It does  not work in GUI emacs too.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem as a newbie Spacemacs user. I discovered the problem was you have to hit the `fd` keys together *very* quickly (much more quickly than in Vim) or it doesn't take. Try adding this line to the `user-config` section of your `.spacemacs` file:

```
(setq-default evil-escape-delay 0.2)
```